# How do I prevent posts from randomly repeating on post archive using pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I added pagination to a custom post-type's archive using the `paginate_links()` function provided by Wordpress. The page numbers and paging itself work fine but posts start to re-appear at random whenever I go to another page.

Example:

> ### Page 1
>
> 1. Product 1
> 2. Product 2
> 3. Product 3
> 4. Product 4
> 5. Product 5
> 6. Product 6
>
> ### Page 2
>
> 1. Product 7
> 2. Product 4 (duplicate)
> 3. Product 8
> 4. Product 9
> 5. Product 2 (duplicate)
> 6. Product 10

And so on. No idea if this has any significance but it's always the same couple of posts that re-appear in the lists. Even after a hard refresh page 2 from the example would still look the same.

This is the custom query I used including the loop:

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

// CUSTOM QUERY ARGS
$product_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
  )
);

// CATEGORY FILTER
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat']) {
  $category = $_GET['cat'];
  $product_args['tax_query'][] = array('taxonomy' => 'product-category', 'terms' => $category, 'field' => 'slug', 'operator' => 'IN');
}

$product_query = new WP_Query($product_args);

// THE LOOP
if ($product_query->have_posts()) {
  while ($product_query->have_posts()): $product_query->the_post();
    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'product');
  endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

And the `paginate_links()` function as documented on [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links):

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$total_pages = $product_query->max_num_pages;
$translated = __( 'Page', 'project' ); // Supply translatable string
$current_page = max(1, get_query_var( 'paged' ));

echo paginate_links(array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '/page/%#%',
  'current' => $current_page,
  'total' => $total_pages,
  'prev_text' => '<i class="far fa-angle-left"></i>',
  'next_text' => '<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>',
  'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
)); ?>
```

I basically copied it from the documentation making only necessary changes to suit my setup.

I'll also add the rewrite rule I added to `functions.php` for the pagination links in case this could have anything to do with the issue:

```
/**
 * Fix pagination on archive pages
 */
function pagination_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(get_option('category_base') . '/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=' . get_option('category_base') . '&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'pagination_rewrite');
```

I read that custom queries can mess up pagination functions but they have a section specifically for handling Custom Queries in the documentation and I made sure to follow it to the letter. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Are your pagination links actually passing on the value of the `cat` parameter? If not, you’d probably be executing a _different_ query when you start using those pagination links.

Comment: The `cat` parameter is only passed to the 'tax_query' in the query arguments when it's selected on the front end. After `cat` has been set the pagination links adjust to the amount of posts that are available as intended so I don't think that' it.

Comment: _“the pagination links adjust to the amount of posts that are available”_ - and that is still the case _after_ you paginated for the first time? That you get the right number when they are _first_ generated is not surprising - at _that_ time, the `cat` parameter was still available.

Comment: Yes the pagination links always appear to show het correct amount pages. Clicking through the pages does not alter the total amount of pages. When the query is adjusted by setting `cat` on the front end the pagination adjusts to the new amount of pages. You wouldn't know there's anything wrong until you pay attention to the posts being displayed and start to notice posts re-appearing on certain pages.

Comment: Nah, I’m still not convinced. Depending on what amount of products you have in what categories, that could still lead to an amount of pages that “appears” right … It simply makes no sense to expect proper results, if you make the initial query with limitation to a certain category - and then don’t see to it that this limitation is applied when you look at the following pages. Each of those pages executes a new query - so the parameters must be the same as well, if you want to get a result that makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure if I follow. I should be able to limit or filter the query by category. That's what the `tax_query` is for, right? Should I try removing the category filter part (`if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat'])...`) and remove the `tax_query` from the args to see if that changes anything?

Comment: _“That's what the tax_query is for, right?”_ – yes; but you are only adding the parameters for that, if $_GET['cat'] was actually set. If your pagination links do _not_ pass this parameter along - then `if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat'])` will not be true on that next page, so you won’t be adding any tax query parameters - and that means you’d be executing a _different_ query than you did on the first page.

Comment: Ohh I think I get it! With that in mind I tried setting up a `tax_query` for a random term in the initial query args as a test. This however didn't fix the problem. Duplicate posts are still scattered throughout the pages.

Comment: These products don’t by any chance all have the same post_date? You are ordering by date here, which includes the time - but if those products did get imported into the system somehow, it might be they have the exact same value. Maybe not all of them, but the first X of them … in that case, you would need a second order criterion, because otherwise all post in a “group” with the same post date would still be in random order inside that group … that could also possibly explain the effect you’re seeing here.

Comment: As a matter of fact they do. Products are imported as CSV and have the exact same upload time. I checked a couple and they're the same up to the minute... I changed the order to `'name'` and that appears to have removed duplicate posts when an initial `tax_query` is set. But when I remove the initial query in order to show all posts (until a filter has been set) the last two pages are left empty returning a 404 error on the page.